# Prevent permission changes on sftp server

Tags: permissions, sftp

I know, another permissions question, but I couldn't find an answer...

I set up an sftp server with chrooted access by several users. The users have access to shared folders. On the shared folders I set the sgid bit so that every new subfolder in the shared folder is owned by the same group. Now some users (clients) seem to upload or create folders without write permissions for the group. That results in the problem that other users are unable to create another folder inside. How would I force the clients to create folders with certain permissions?

In the `vsftpd.conf` I can just do

```
chmod_enable=NO
```

which solves the problem for ftp, but for the `sshd_config` I can't find something similar. `umask` doesn't seem to help since this only restricts permissions.

PS: Ubuntu 16.04.1, OpenSSH-Server 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu1

Answer (score 1):

`sftp-server` have option to deny this using `-P` switch. Modifying your `sshd_config` in server setting

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -P setstat,fsetstat
```

should do the job.

Comment: hm, sounds right, but doesn't work yet. When I access the server with filezilla I can still change the permissions of folders. And yes, I did restart the service after I changed the sshd_config...

Comment: Does it allow you to do that in the UI, or is the change actually applied to the server?

Comment: It really changes it on the server. I checked it via ssh...